# Multiple chords overlap in modal interchange chords from different modes

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

For instance, in the key of Cm we could borrow Am7-5 from C Dorian mode. But also C Jazz minor has Am7-5. Also F7 from C Dorian mode and F7 from C Jazz minor.
There will be more in different modes if I keep looking.
But what are the differences in these situations? Is it ultimately the scale??

Comment: So are you asking - if are in C minor and you borrow Am7-5, how do you know what scale you're borrowing it from?

Comment: @topomorto Yes , and whats the difference if I choose either one

Comment: It seems like the same general question as your recent one [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/69242/i-want-to-use-a-modal-interchange-chord-but-i-cant-find-which-mode-scale-im-bo), just a different specific case..?

Comment: @topomorto Oh I see I thought maybe there will be another answer or something..

Comment: I think the general answer is the same - were you looking for more detail, or suggestions for perspectives to see these *specific* chords from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Borrowing' is just a device for making you happy that using a certain chord is 'allowed'.  If you're preparing an excursion to another key, 'borrowing' some chords from that key can be effective - for instance if you're in C major and contemplating a move to Eb major (a very common modulation, beloved of the 'Golden Age' songwriters) it can be a good idea to throw in some Fm chords.  Fm is a very common chromatic colour in C major, and is also a gateway to a ii, V, I modulation into Eb, that would be Fm7, Bb7, Eb.

Apart from that, I really wouldn't worry too much about 'borrowing'.  If you're noodling around in C major, like I said Fm is a common chord to use.  If it ISN'T the preparation for a modulation, 'borrowing' isn't a particularly useful concept.  Just let it be a modified diatonic chord.  It fits in well because two of its notes are diatonic.  That's sufficient 'permission' to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Sorry about being too much stuck in the theory and always trying to find some reasons..But I just want to perfectly know what I'm exactly doing and also master the basic rules before I start bending them..But I still always appreciate your answers !